LaTeX (on overleaf) keeps cutting off my polynomial plots
Here is the preamble and the code for the graph:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,width=15cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-6, xmax=15, ymin=-10, ymax=10,
    axis lines=middle, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
   % xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
    ytick={-10,...,10},xtick={-10,...,15}]
        \addplot[color=blue, samples=50]{-1/1000*(x+2)^2*(x-5)*(x-10)^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


It should display the whole thing, i.e., the right part below the x axis. Am I missing something?
Note: If you are wondering about the
% xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty

I was making some graphs with no tick mark labels and some with labels, so I just comment out that line when I want to show the tick labels.

If you are wondering about the % xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty, I was making some graphs with no tick mark labels and some with labels,  so I just comment out that line when I want to show the tick labels.

Welcome! ......

The default domain is -5:5 (page 55 of the manual). Since you've not defined a domain, this is what pgfplots uses.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,width=15cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-6,xmax=15,ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    axis lines=middle, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    % xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
    ytick={-10,...,10},xtick={-10,...,15}]
    \addplot[color=blue, samples=50,domain=-6:15]{-1/1000*(x+2)^2*(x-5)*(x-10)^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You might have been thinking that
xmin=-6,xmax=15,ymin=-10,ymax=10

was sufficient to determine the interval(s) over which the function would be plotted, but these values determine only the extent of the axes. They do not affect the values the function takes or can take when constructing the plot.

@Willie Wong Wouldn't it be better to link to CTAN?

the link goes directly to the domain entry in the pgfplots manual; linking to CTAN would bring up a manual that the OP has to search through. Considering how big the manual is, I think in this case an argument can be made for linking to the HTML version.

@WillieWong The HTML version is significantly harder to read, though. At least for me. Anyway, I'm not really comfortable not linking CTAN if I'm going to link at all, so I've included both. It is possible to link to anchors in PDFs on CTAN but either this PDF isn't the kind you can link to or I don't know how to do it.

both is better than one is better than none, I say.

@WillieWong The CTAN version is also horribly slow. I guess it depends on the mirror. I still prefer texdoc ;).

That is exactly what I was doing @cfr! Thank you! And thank you for including the link to a manual! For the future, Is there a repository of package manuals somewhere?

@KelliA. CTAN (https://ctan.org/) is an archive of TeX software, including most packages. The documentation is almost always available there - unless the documentation doesn't exist, basically. I've (just) discovered https://texdoc.org/index.html but know absolutely nothing about it. If you had a local installation of TeX, the best is to bring up the documentation on your system (if you installed the docs) because that is guaranteed to match the version of the package you're using. But I don't think you can do that on Overleaf.
